# XslCompiledTransform.Load takes 15 seconds on first run

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm loading XSL from an XML document using this code (XSL has embedded data):

```
public void SetHtmlSourceFromXmlDocument(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transform.Load(xmlDocument);

    // ...
}
```

On customer computers `transform.Load(xmlDocument)` will take 15 seconds the first time. Subsequent calls will take ~1 ms. Software restart: first call takes again 15 seconds.

This happens only with our server build, a build from my computer (also release) will run just fine (the only thing I know that the server build signs assemblies).
This problem also occurs only on non-developer systems (no Visual Studio, no internet access, only intranet). On one of the problematic systems this problem disappeared, but I have no idea why (It seems I did something buy I don't know what, can't reproduce the error on this system anymore).

I also tried `transform.Load(xmlDocument, null, null)` or supplying my own `XmlResolver` (`GetEntity` is never called), because I read that `XslCompiledTransform` could try to access the xmlns namespace urls to validate the document (maybe I misunderstood that).

I can't install Visual Studio on these machines for debugging.
Has someone an idea what could cause this or what I could try to find the issue?

Xml Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" encoding="utf-8" href="#"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:data="http://zeiss.com/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <data:data>
    <calibrationLog>
      <name>DetectorOffsetCalibration</name>
      <entry timestamp="2015-03-25T18:49:24.0313832+01:00" userGroup="Customer" level="Info" indent="0" message="Created at Wednesday, 25 March 2015 18:49:24 (+01 UTC) by Developer on ZEISS-PC." />
    </calibrationLog>
  </data:data>
  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data:data" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="calibrationLog">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
          html, body, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; background-color: #FFFFFF;; }
          p { white-space: pre-wrap; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3 style="margin: 0.2em 1em;">Calibration Log "<xsl:value-of select="name" />"</h3>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
          <xsl:variable name="style">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Debug'">display: none</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Info'">color: Black; background-color: White</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'IntermediateResult'">color: Black; background-color: CornflowerBlue</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Result'">color: Black; background-color: YellowGreen</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'SilentWarning'">color: Black; background-color: Yellow</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Warn'">color: Black; background-color: Yellow</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Error'">color: White; background-color: OrangeRed</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Device'">color: Lightgray; background-color: White</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'Section'">color: Darkmagenta; background-color: White; font-weight: Bold; border-color: darkmagenta; border-width: 10; border-top-style: Double; border-bottom-style: Double; margin: 0.5em 0; padding-top: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 0.3em</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@level = 'SubSection'">color: Darkmagenta; background-color: White; font-weight: Bold;</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="currentIndent" select="1.25 + @indent" />
          <p style="{$style}; padding-left: {$currentIndent}em; text-indent: -1em;">
            <xsl:value-of select="@message" />
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you always calling `Load` or is `Load` only happening once and then everything after is just `Transform`? It will take some time to compile everything first call. On top of that, you are probably also getting bit by the JIT compiler having to compile that code. Everything is slower the first time around which is why some will do pre-initialization routines at the start of their applications.

Comment: I call everytime load, followed by transform.

Comment: Then it is just going to be the JIT. If you want to speed it up, when the program first starts, create a throwaway instance of that class so it gets compiled before they actually attempt to use. You may need to actually call a method so it doesn't get ignored by the compiler. That should make the "first" call faster.

Comment: But why this happens only on some machines? And I can't believe the JIT will take 15 seconds. If it were 50..100 ms OK, but 15 seconds?

Comment: Here's something that has some nice info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830218/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-pre-jitting-assemblies-in-net  I don't actually know @ayhjar. Those computers could just be slow, different versions of .NET with different updates. Without actually being able to run a profiler on your application on those machines, there's really no way of telling. Are you building in Release mode with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Yes, Release with Optimize Code